# How to create a new course category in the moodle?

Tags: mysql, moodle

I need to create some moodle's itens directly in database.

I have the query to insert a new moodle course, and the rules to create the course context (in `mdl_context`) and it's work well.

```
INSERT INTO mdl_course (category,fullname,shortname) VALUES (1,'NewCourse','C1')
```

Also needs to insert a new `moodle category,` but in this case a simple insert query dont works

i don't know how to discover the parameters to create a new the category context in mdl_context

```
INSERT INTO `moodle_db`.`mdl_course_categories` (`name`, `idnumber`, `description`, `descriptionformat`, `sortorder`, `timemodified`, `depth`, `path`) VALUES ('New category', '', '<p>some text</p>', 1, 50000, 1392726085, 1, '/5');
```

About the parameters, aparently the `path` in a context  is about what course is in what category, and the `depth` is `'2'` to `categories` and `'3'` to `courses`. But i have no ideia about the contextlevel

```
INSERT INTO `moodle_db`.`mdl_context` (`contextlevel`, `instanceid`, `path`, `depth`) VALUES (40, 3, '/1/20', 2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by using the moodle REST api

I did this script based on the examples found here [sample-ws-clients](https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients)

```
$token = 'my_auth_token';
$domainname = 'http://localhost/moodle';
$functionname = 'core_course_create_categories';
$restformat = 'json';

$category = new stdClass();
$category->name = 'Example';
$category->parent = 0;
$category->description = '<p>text</p>';
$category->descriptionformat = 1;
$categories = array( $category);
$params = array('categories' => $categories);

/// REST CALL
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;
require_once('./curl.php');
$curl = new curl;
//if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
$restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
$resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
print_r($resp);
```

This method creates the context automatically